# Oracle case/replace pivot grouping result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following query to display pivoted table:

```
select deptno, clerk, salesman,
            manager, analyst, president
       from (select deptno, job, sal
               from emp )
      pivot( sum(sal) for job in
      ( 'CLERK' as clerk,
       'SALESMAN' as salesman,
       'MANAGER' as manager,
       'ANALYST' as analyst,
      'PRESIDENT' as president ) )
    order by deptno
   /
```

And result:

```
   DEPTNO      CLERK   SALESMAN    MANAGER    ANALYST  PRESIDENT
----------    -------   --------    -------    -------  ---------
        10       1300         0        2450        0         6000
        20       1900         0        2975       6000       0
        30        950       5600       2850        0         0
```

But now I have to identify the ones we are have value set - it is replace any number by 1 ( when salary is set) so I will have

```
   DEPTNO      CLERK   SALESMAN    MANAGER    ANALYST  PRESIDENT
----------    -------   --------    -------    -------  ---------
        10       1            0        1        0        1
```

ETC.

Is it possible somehow using case ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `CASE WHEN sum(sal) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in the subquery:

```
select deptno, clerk, salesman, manager, analyst, president
from (select deptno, job,
             max(case when sal > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as salflag
      from emp )
pivot( max(salflag) for job in
      ('CLERK' as clerk,
       'SALESMAN' as salesman,
       'MANAGER' as manager,
       'ANALYST' as analyst,
       'PRESIDENT' as president )
      )
order by deptno;
```

I also think the conditional aggregation approach is pretty easy:

```
select deptno,
       max(case when job = 'CLERK' and sal > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as clerk,
       max(case when job = 'SALESMAN' and sal > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as salesman,
       max(case when job = 'MANAGER' and sal > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as manager,
       max(case when job = 'ANALYST' and sal > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as analyst,
       max(case when job = 'PRESIDENT' and sal > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as president
from emp
group by deptno;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it after the `pivot` is done.

```
with pvt as (select deptno, clerk, salesman,
        manager, analyst, president
   from (select deptno, job, sal
           from emp )
  pivot( sum(sal) for job in
  ( 'CLERK' as clerk,
   'SALESMAN' as salesman,
   'MANAGER' as manager,
   'ANALYST' as analyst,
  'PRESIDENT' as president ) )
order by deptno)
select deptno, 
case when clerk > 0 then 1 else 0 end as clerk,
case when salesman > 0 then 1 else 0 end as salesman,
case when manager > 0 then 1 else 0 end as manager,
case when analyst > 0 then 1 else 0 end as analyst,
case when president > 0 then 1 else 0 end as president
from pvt
```